# Mod_rewrite short to query string

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am migrating from one content system to another and need to map old URLs to new ones.  Old ones are short, new ones are longer (at least for migration.

Old URLS look like this:

http://example.com/sport/0/article/16814.php

where 16814 is a record ID.  New ones look like this:

index.php?module=stories&type=user&func=display&tid=3&pid=16814

"sport" in the old URL maps to "3" in the new, but in the same position as sport might be "column" which maps to "4".  The record ID maps the same in both instances.

If conditional mapping isn't possible, I could do two separate rewrites...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't that many `tid`'s, you can just enumerate through them:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?sport/.*/([0-9]+)\.php /index.php?module=stories&type=user&func=display&tid=3&pid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?column/.*/([0-9]+)\.php /index.php?module=stories&type=user&func=display&tid=4&pid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

etc.